# Looping through uneven Excel data to create consistency

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Sample Data]
I receive data from accounting which is an Excel spreadsheet automatically formatted by the world's dumbest POS system (which can't be modified). The data contain a weird combination of customer and purchase data (e.g. they're co-mingled). I need to separate the customer and receipt data. Please see screenshot of sample data. The actual data is thousands of lines, but it's all formatted like this.

Any row with a date in the first cell is the customer record, and the line or lines which follow it and do not have data in the first or second columns are the receipt data.

What I need to do is detect rows which are receipt data and copy them to another worksheet, deleting each row from the first sheet as it gets moved to the second sheet. That way, I'll be left with customer records on the first sheet and receipts on the second. The only hitch is that I need to copy the receipt number (the numeric data on column 5) and referral code (column 13) from the "customer" row to each of the "receipt" rows for that customer. I'm getting hung up on the loop.

In my code you'll see how I'm "detecting" receipt data (e.g. looking for two blank columns). That works, but it's spitting out the same records a bunch of times, so clearly I'm screwed up in the loop somewhere. See second image for what is getting spit out on the second worksheet. Please help!!!!

```
Public Sub MovePurchases()

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim LR As Long
Dim nLR As Long
Dim arrCount As Integer
Dim arrLBound As Integer
Dim arrUBound As Integer
Dim numRowsBlank As Integer
Dim rowLoopInt As Integer
Dim rcptNumber As Integer
Dim xOffset As Integer
Dim refCode As String

Dim nws As Worksheet
Dim ows As Worksheet

Set nws = Sheets("Purchases")
Set ows = ActiveSheet
' Find row count and set it as the upper boundary
LR = ows.UsedRange.Rows(ows.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

For x = 1 To LR
' Since we are detecting blank values in the CURRENT row, we must subtract
' 1 to get the value of the receipt number which is always in the precedeing row
    xOffset = x - 1
    If IsNumeric(Range("E" & x).Value) = True Then
    rcptNumber = ows.Cells(x, 5).Value
    refCode = ows.Cells(x, 13).Value
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Cells(x, 1).Value) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(x, 2).Value) = True Then
    'We know that the row is a receipt record.
    'Count the number of rows until the next blank a and b column
    numRowsBlank = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    For rowLoopInt = 1 To numRowsBlank
        Range("A" & x).Value = rcptNumber
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    nLR = nws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ows.Rows(x).Copy nws.Cells(nLR, "A")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
        Next rowLoopInt
    
    End If

Next x

End Sub
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Public Sub MovePurchases()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsP As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, LR As Long, LC As Long, flagCol As Long
    Dim rw As Range, x As Long, rcptNumber, refCode, rwDest As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or (eg) ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsP = wb.Worksheets("Purchases")
    Set wsData = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    LR = LastOccupiedRow(wsData)
    LC = LastOccupiedColumn(wsData)
    Debug.Print "last row", LR, "last col", LC
    flagCol = LC + 2
    
    'first destination row
    Set rwDest = wsP.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For x = 1 To LR
        Set rw = wsData.Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, LC)  'row of data
        If Application.CountA(rw) > 0 Then         'not a blank row?
            If Len(rw.Cells(1).Value) > 0 And IsNumeric(rw.Cells(5).Value) Then
                rcptNumber = rw.Cells(5).Value
                refCode = rw.Cells(13).Value
            Else
                rwDest.Cells(1).Value = rcptNumber
                rwDest.Cells(2).Value = refCode
                rw.Copy rwDest.Cells(3)
                wsData.Cells(x, flagCol).Value = "x" 'flag purchase row for deletion
                Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1)
            End If
        Else
            wsData.Cells(x, flagCol).Value = "x" 'flag blank row for deletion
        End If
    Next x
    
    'delete flagged rows
    wsData.Columns(flagCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete
   
End Sub

Function LastOccupiedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedRow = f.Row
End Function
Function LastOccupiedColumn(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedColumn = f.Column
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!! Works like an absolute charm :D